# How do you plot a ohlc chart with a set range (invariable) of 1 hour using dash-plotly?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

This is my code:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from datetime import timedelta

file_name = 'temp_copy.csv'
file_path = 'C:\\Users\\xxx\\' + str( file_name )
df = pd.read_csv( 'file_path' )
df['period_close'] = pd.to_datetime( df.period_close )
df['year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex( df['period_close'] ).year
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex( df['period_close'] ).month
df['month_str'] = df.month.apply(str).str.zfill(2)
df['slider_id'] = ( df.year - 2017 ) * 12 + df.month # has to be linear
df['slider_label'] = df.year.apply(str).str.cat( df.month_str ).apply(int)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

ids = df.slider_id.unique().tolist()
labels = [{ 'label': str( i ) } for i in df.slider_label.unique().tolist() ]

marks = dict(zip( ids, labels )) 

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),

    html.Div(children='''
        Dash: A web application framework for Python.
    '''),

    dcc.Graph(id="my-graph"),

    html.Div([
        dcc.RangeSlider(id="select-range",
                        marks=marks,
                        min=df.slider_id.min(),
                        max=df.slider_id.max(),
                        value=[7, 8]
                        )
        ], 
        style={"padding-top": 100,}
    )
], className="container")

@app.callback(
    Output("my-graph", 'figure'),
    [Input("select-range", 'value')]
)

def update_figure(selected):
    print( selected[0] )
    fromYear = int( selected[0] / 12 + 2017 )
    fromMonth = int( selected[0] % 12 )
    toYear = int( selected[1] / 12 + 2017 )
    toMonth = int( selected[1] % 12 )

    dff = df[
          ( df.year >= fromYear ) 
        & ( df.month >= fromMonth ) 
        & ( df.year <= toYear )
        & ( df.month <= toMonth )
    ]

    trace = go.Candlestick(x=dff['period_close'],
                           open=dff['price'],
                           high=dff['high'],
                           low=dff['low'],
                           close=dff['close'],
                           increasing={'line': {'color': '#00CC94'}},
                           decreasing={'line': {'color': '#F50030'}}
            )
    return {
        'data': [trace],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title=f"Prices",
            xaxis={
                'rangeslider': {
                    'visible': True, 
                    'range': [ df.period_close.min(), df.period_close.min() + timedelta(hours=1) ]
                },
                'autorange': True,
            },
            yaxis={
                "title": f'Price'
            }
        )}

server = app.server # the Flask app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

I can not provide you with the data, but it starts at 2017 and provides the columns: open, high, low, close, period_close. I found the rangeslider wouldnt do what I wanted, although i may have done something wrong. It required an int value, in a linear format for equal spacing so i have simply got the year - 2017 + month to have a linear spread.

My problem in detail:
I have a huge dataset of 1 minute OHLC data from 2017 (July) through to Jan 2019. I want to be able to plot a 1 hour (roughly) window across my screen, with a range slider underneath that i can drag to get different timeframes. If possible, I would like the slider to not be variable in width ( ~1 hour or so ).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to make the range slider lock in the width. However, you could just use the normal slider.

```py
dcc.Slider(
        min=0,
        max=19,
        marks={
            x: '{} to {}'.format(x, x+1)
            for x in range(20)
        },
        value=0
    )
```

You'd have to change it, of course, but that's the general idea. Would that work?